# Recovering the continuity equation in the Newtonian limit for a perfect fluid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, approximations

I have been trying to show that $T^{0\nu}_{;\nu} = 0$, where $T$ is the stress-energy tensor, reduces to the flat spacetime continuity equation in weak gravitational field.

Taking the metric to be $ds^2 = -(1+2\phi)dt^2 + (1-2\phi)dx^idx^i$, with $\phi$ being the static Newtonian potential, I worked out the Christoffel symbols to be $\Gamma^0_{i0} = \partial_i\phi$, $\Gamma^i_{00} = \partial^i\phi$ and $\Gamma^i_{jk} = \delta_{jk}\partial^i\phi - \delta^i_j\partial_k\phi - \delta^i_k\partial_j\phi$. For a perfect fluid in the Newtonian limit the components of $T$ are - $T^{00} = \rho$, $T^{0j} = \rho v^j$ and $T^{ij} = \rho v^iv^j + p\delta^{ij}$ (assuming $\rho \gg p$ and $v^j \ll 1$)

Using the above:

$T^{00}_{;0} = T^{00}_{,0} + \Gamma^0_{\alpha 0}T^{\alpha0} + \Gamma^0_{\alpha 0}T^{0\alpha} = \partial_0\rho + 2\partial_i\phi v^i\rho$

$T^{0j}_{;j} = T^{0j}_{,j} + \Gamma^0_{\alpha j}T^{\alpha j} + \Gamma^j_{\alpha j}T^{0\alpha} = \partial_j(v^j\rho) + \partial_i\phi v^i\rho - \partial_k\phi v^k\rho = \partial_j(v^j\rho)$

Putting everything together, I got:

$T^{0\nu}_{;\nu} = T^{00}_{;0}+T^{0j}_{;j}$,

$\partial_0\rho + \partial_j(v^j\rho) + 2\partial_i\phi v^i\rho = 0$.

This seems to imply that the standard continuity equation under gravity can only hold in circular orbits ($\nabla\phi \cdot v$ = 0), however, this should not be the case. Where does the above reasoning go wrong?